# 2000s TV-movie/film where a futuristic tank/AFV crew end up dying and the last survivor wrenched something from behind his neck

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Watched on TV sometime between 1998 and 2002. Definitely European/American film.

There's a female member on the crew. At first they're doing a regular mission, later one by one the crews end up dying/killing each other. The last survivor wrenched something from behind his neck after killing another (both male), leaving his vehicle and see the beach outside.